# multiple portal dnn with windows azure

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I have a dnn 7 instance I am thinking of moving to windows azure.  How do I configure the DNS for the various portals.  I am aware that you use a cname record with the dns to point to the top level/host portal.  But where do you point the "sub" portals cname record.  Is it at the same host portal's azure address ie: mysite.azurewebsites.net.

Or is there another way to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to direct all the traffic you need to your instance(s) (i.e. yoursites.azurewebsites.net).

But you can also use `A` records, not only `CNAME` records. Please read carefully [this article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/).